# Same Windows 10 Insider Build one 2 system, still differences in UI

Tags: windows, windows-10, terminal, windows-insider

I have a notebook and a desktop, both are running the newest Windows 10 insider Build `14901.rs_prerelease.160805-1700` yet there are differences between these to.

My notebooks terminal and focused windows looks like this.

[image]

But on my desktop it doesn't:

[image]
(hint: terminal font is different)

There are also some new features for the terminal i'd love on my desktop.

So why is it that both supposedly running the very same OS look so differently?

Comment: I know you can change the font in the cmd window by right clicking the title bar or in the text area (one of those) and changing the properties.  Not quite sure about the focusing though.

Comment: You are not using the current Version 1607 build.

Comment: Might clarify your using an insider preview build, by saying your using the current build, that implies the current stable build not a preview build

Comment: @Ramhound yes I have, on both systems the build number under settings is completely the same